# Monad transformers - Scalaz - List[Future[String\/String]] to Future[String\/String]

Tags: scala, future, scalaz, monad-transformers, either

I wonder how I can transform a `List[Future[String\/String]]` to `Future[String\/String]`.

In fact, I just want to apply for each element of the list `EitherT.apply`.

What I want looks like this :

```
val result: EitherT[Future, String, String] =
    for{
        _                     <- EitherT.apply(fun(arg1))
        _                     <- EitherT.apply(fun(arg2))
        res                   <- EitherT.apply(fun(arg3))
    } yield res
result.run

// ...

def fun(arg1: MyType): Future[String\/String] = ...
```

In this example, I would like to set as input the function `fun` and a list (of n elements) of arguments for the function `fun` (here : `List(arg1, arg2, arg3)`).

But I don't know how to manage with Futures.
Is it possible to keep the asynchrony ?

Comment: [`Future.sequence`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future$@sequence[A,M[X]<:TraversableOnce[X]](in:M[scala.concurrent.Future[A]])(implicitcbf:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[M[scala.concurrent.Future[A]],A,M[A]],implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[M[A]]) can do it.

Comment: I think you've forgotten something in the output type - you input a `List` but you only get one element out?

Comment: Thanks ! 
@GáborBakos Future.sequence is nice but what about the performances ?
@lmm In fact I just want to check one after the other the result of the `fun` foreach element of the list. If one return Left (fail) return this one otherwise return \/-("Ok").
I have found a way to do it. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to do it but without using EitherT.apply.

```
def seqCheck(elements: List[Element]): Future[String\/String] = elements match {
    case element :: tail  =>
        fun(element) flatMap {
            case \/-(_) =>
                seqCheck(tail)
            case -\/(e) => Future{
                -\/(e)
            }
        }
    case Nil                =>
        Future {
            \/-("Ok")
        }
}
```

It not as nice as I would like it to be but it seems to work.
If somebody knows a best way...